# In Android Studio XML source code, if I reference something by writing "@color/primaryColor", would it only look for a class named "color"?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources, android-color

So I've been asking many people and everyone told me both R and color are classes that are auto-generated. So when I'm referencing in an XML file by writing `@color/primaryColor`, I assume it is looking for a class named `color` because color is literally a class. But hypothetically, if there's a file named `color` and a folder named `color`, then what would it prioritize? would it FIRST look for a class named `color` and then look for a file and then a folder? What would it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

When you set @color/colorPrimary in xml then it reads from app/res/values/colors.xml.
"colors.xml" has 3 default color names set and you can create your own colors inside the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Neither: it looks for [resources of type `color`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color).  See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources) for an overview of resource types in general.

These resources are processed from your XML files by the [Android Asset Packaging Tool (AAPT)](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) as part of your build process.  The filename isn't important: the colors are often, but don't need to be, in a `colors.xml` file.

There's no way to define these resources from Java, either by creating a class, folder, or by any other method.